# Putting MySQL result into php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to get results from a table into a PHP variable so I can display all the results in a continuous loop. Currently, with my code, only the last result is showing up. The goal is to have every the headline and content result display in a loop.  TIA for your help.

```
 <html>
 <head>
<style>
   #table1{
 border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 display:none;
 width: 60%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }

th{
text-align:center;
}
td,th{
border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<? if ($query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Announcements_Current`"))
 {
/* select all information from the table and take it into the page  */
$query->execute(); 
  while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$head = $result['headline'];
$content = $result['content'];
 }
 }
  ?>
  <table id="table1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
  <th>
  <h1>
  <?php echo $head;
  ?>
  </h1>
  </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>
   <font size="4">
    <?php echo $content;
  ?>
  </font>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table1').fadeIn(2000);
$('#table1').delay(5000);
$('#table1').fadeOut(2000);
}  
 )};
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Echo inside of the while loop. You assign, the overwrite your variables until only the last is left standing.

Comment: Jay is correct. Echo inside of your while loop. The While loops until it has itterated through your entire database table. Only the last row remains in your variables as it overwrites every time inside the while. Echoing inside the while will echo all of your results.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I did this but now it's only showing the first result. Any ideas?

Comment: I added an example as answer :)
Good luck :)